# How do you extract a parameter or value inside an array?

Tags: php, json

I have the following code:

```
$responseretrieveUserDetails = CRSMClient::retrieveUserDetails($userId);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($responseretrieveUserDetails);
echo "</pre>";

$obj = json_decode($responseretrieveUserDetails );

 $autoFlag = false;
    $prod = false;
    $log = false;
    $mac = false;
    $auto = "";
    $value = 0;

    foreach($obj["userAttributeList"]["attributeValues"] as $key => $val){
            $auto = $val["attributeName"];
            $value = $val["attributeValue"];


            if($auto == "Auto" && $value == 1){
                $autoFlag = true;
                }

            if($auto == "Prod" && $value == 1){
                $prod = true;
            }

            if($auto == "Logistics" && $value == 1){
                $log = true;
            }

            if($auto == "Mac" && $value == 1){
                $mac = true;
            }
        }
```

$responseretrieveUserDetails is returning the following:

```
(
        [id] => 636
        [description] => customer2802@camera.com
        [parentBusinessUserId] => 155
        [statusId] => 1
        [roleTypeId] => 49
        [defaultLanguageId] => 2
        [userExternalIdList] => Array
            (
                [externalIds] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [externalId] => customer2802@camera.com
                                [defaultFlag] => 1
                                [type] => email
                                [statusId] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [userAttributeList] => Array
            (
                [attributeValues] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 9
                                [attributeName] => name
                                [attributeValue] => customer2802@camera.com
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 100015
                                [attributeName] => Mac
                                [attributeValue] => 1
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 100014
                                [attributeName] => Logistics
                                [attributeValue] => 1
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 100018
                                [attributeName] => timezone
                                [attributeValue] => GMT+00:00
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 14
                                [attributeName] => email
                                [attributeValue] => myemail@mail.com
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 100012
                                [attributeName] => Auto
                                [attributeValue] => 1
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 100013
                                [attributeName] => Prod
                                [attributeValue] => 1
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 100007
                                [attributeName] => TC_WEB
                                [attributeValue] => 1
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [attributeId] => 100009
                                [attributeName] => TC_Vx_WEB
                                [attributeValue] => 1
                                [languageId] => 2
                                [languageName] => en
                                [statusId] => 1
                                [statusName] => active
                            )

                    )

            )

        [offeringList] => Array
            (
                [offerings] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 16
                                [name] => CAM
                                [statusId] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [offeringDetailsRetrievedList] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 16
                        [name] => CAM
                        [statusId] => 1
                    )

            )

        [businessUserAttributeList] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 9
                        [attributeName] => name
                        [attributeValue] => customer2802@camera.com
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 100015
                        [attributeName] => Mac_Operator
                        [attributeValue] => 1
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 100014
                        [attributeName] => Logistics
                        [attributeValue] => 1
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 100018
                        [attributeName] => timezone
                        [attributeValue] => GMT+00:00
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 14
                        [attributeName] => email
                        [attributeValue] => myemail@mail.com
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 100012
                        [attributeName] => Auto_Maintenance
                        [attributeValue] => 1
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 100013
                        [attributeName] => Prod_Director
                        [attributeValue] => 1
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 100007
                        [attributeName] => TC_WEB
                        [attributeValue] => 1
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [attributeId] => 100009
                        [attributeName] => TC_Vx_WEB
                        [attributeValue] => 1
                        [languageId] => 2
                        [languageName] => en
                        [statusId] => 1
                        [statusName] => active
                    )

            )

        [externalId] => customer2802@camera.com
        [externalIdType] => email
        [mail] => myemail@mail.com
    )
```

I dont know what's wrong with my code but my foreach statement is not returning anything? I want to get the value for attributeName and attribute value of Mac,  Prod, Auto and Logistics and return a true if attribute value is 1 and false if it's zero. Help?

Comment: Where is `$obj` defined?

Comment: @kerbholz sorry wasnt able to include . edited the code

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($responseretrieveUserDetails ); ` are you sure `responseretrieveUserDetails ` has json string?

Comment: "_$responseretrieveUserDetails is returning the following:_" That already looks like an array, no need to `json_decode()` it

Comment: okay, then how do i get the values inside those arrays? I tried using 
    $obj = $responseretrieveUserDetails;
  $jan = $obj[USERATTRIBUTELIST]; but nothing is showing up

Comment: try `echo "<pre>";
print_r($responseretrieveUserDetails->userAttributeList->attributeValues);
echo "</pre>";`

Comment: @fmsthird so frustrating, still nothing :((((